# javascript regex not working properly for uppercase non-digit character

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to test a uppercase non-digit character.

```
var myReg = new RegExp('\\D', 'i');
myReg.test('A'); //returns true
myReg.text('a'); //returns true
```

jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/rikoxoveti/edit?js,console

It returns true for both upper and lower case.

I expect the second case `myReg.text('a')` should return false. But it retuns true.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'i'` means case insensitive ... `\D` means non digit

Comment: I understand. thank you. But I would like check whether the character is uppercase.


var myReg = new RegExp('\\D');
myReg.test('A'); //returns true
myReg.test('a'); //returns true


Even without 'i' modifier, it returns true for both upper and lower case.

Comment: because `a` and `A` satisfy `\\D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
var myReg =/[A-Z]/;
alert(myReg.test('A')); //returns true
alert(myReg.test('a')); //returns false
```

Comment: Thank you. This will work. But I generate regex dynamically. So I can't use above pattern.
I want to achieve the same result with `\D` meta character

Comment: `\D` finds  every non-digit character like `%,@`etc.so you can not.